# iPhone Objective-C OAuth: A more elegant way to check if a request token is still valid?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oauth, foursquare

I want to do this when the app loads, so I can either ask the user to log in (if not authenticated) or else continue.

The only way I can think of is to call a random request (a GET that requires authentication) and check whether or not I get a valid response, but this seems inelegant. I am using the [Foursquare API](http://groups.google.com/group/foursquare-api/web/api-documentation).

Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a `test` method at `http://api.foursquare.com/v1/test`, but it works without authorisation. You could try sending an authenticated request to that endpoint and see if invalid credentials get rejected or just ignored.